# Auto populate data in Google Spreadsheet from data in separate spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

So, I'm in the situation where I have a Google Spreadsheet with people's names, phone numbers, addresses, etc.

Is it possible to, from another spreadsheet (not sheet, different workbook), search the directory spreadsheet for a name entered into a cell, and then pull certain data and populate it into the new sheet?

Essentially, I want to be able to have a new spreadsheet with a name, phone number, etc column, and have it auto populate the phone number (as well as other data) so I don't have to copy and paste.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is Possible. 
Just follow some simple steps:

1. You create a custom function by writing scripts which will work like simple function inside a Spreadsheet cell for ex: =SUM(A1 +A2) by Opening the Google Spreadsheet(That acts like directory ie. Data like name,contacts etc)  ->Click Tools->Click Script Editor...

A new window will openup and choose spreadsheet option .Here,you can write custom functions which looks like

[image]

Here you write functions (for more info,https://developers.google.com/apps-script/your_first_script#requirements)

2.You create a function that will open your Spreadsheet that contains behaves like directory. A sample function

> function readRows() 
>   {
>   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AszINz88nA9hdEkxa1FIS0wta1FLS2NPUzAyU0lOV1E")
>   var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
>   var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
>   var values = rows.getValues();
>   for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
>       var row = values[i];
>       Logger.log(row);
>     }
>   };

For more info,https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File)

You can Run and Test by pressing Run and selecting function, (it may require permission).

You can view the results in Log Window by Opening View->Logs.

That,it now you can use that function in that cell.